# Migrate Datastax Enterprise Cassandra to Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax

We have currently using DSE 4.8 and 5.12. we want to migrate to apache cassandra .since we don't use spark or search thought save some bucks moving to apache.  can this be achieved without down time. i see sstableloader works other way.  can any one share me the steps to follow to migrate from dse to apache cassandra. something like this from dse to apache. 
https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204226209-Clarification-for-the-use-of-SSTABLELOADER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Figure out what version of Apache Cassandra is being run by DSE. Based on the DSE documentation [DSE 4.8.14](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/RNdse.html#relnotes48__4814comp) is using Apache Cassandra 2.1 and [DSE 5.1](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/releaseNotes/RNdse.html) is using Apache Cassandra 3.11
2. Simplest way to do this is to build another DC (Logical DC per Cassandra) and add it to the existing cluster.
3. As usual, with a "Nodetool Rebuild {from-old-DC}" on to the new DC nodes, let Cassandra take care of streaming data to the new Apache Cassandra nodes naturally.
4. Once data streaming is completed, based on the LoadBalancingPolicy being used by applications, switch their local_dc to DC2 (the new DC). Once the new DC starts taking traffic, shutdown nodes in old DC say DC1 one by one.

Comment: Thanks @disingi. Can same version of dse and apache Cassandra be in the same ring

Comment: Yes they can be.

Comment: @cad Even we are trying to move to apache, If you have already migrated can u plz post in detail what all steps you have followed to achieve this?

Comment: This is incomplete. You need to change dse_system replication strategy and cfs_archive compaction strategy to make them compatible with Cassandra.

Comment: @PedroGordo what you mention are Datastax reared keyspaces which aren’t even available with open source. So they aren’t applicable here

Comment: @dilsingi exactly. Since Apache Cassandra is unfamiliar with these keyspaces, you need to convert them to something that Cassandra can work with, before adding the OS version to the cluster.

Comment: You don’t even need those, pretty much drop them

Comment: !!!watch out for EverywhereStrategy!!!

You must at a minimum change off of that to the mainline cassandra strategies. 

We are going to attempt this from 4.7 DSE to 2.1.X. We'll let you know.

https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/208026816-DSE-EverywhereStrategy-is-not-understood-by-Apache-Cassandra-non-DSE-nodes-and-can-cause-restart-failures

Comment: @ConstanceEustace how was the migration? :)

Comment: @PedroGordo we did not perform this, I believe what we did was sstable load to a new cluster, repoint. It was stage so we could do a bit of scheduled downtime.

Answer (score 0):

1. alter keyspace dse_system and dse_security not using everywhere
2. on non-seed nodes, cleanup cassandra data directory
3. turn on replace in cassandra-env.sh
4. start instance
5. monitoring streaming process using command 'nodetool netstats|grep Receiving'
6. change seeds node definition and rolling restart before finally migrate previous seeds nodes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).