# Getting schema version mismatch error while trying to migrate from DSE Cassandra(6.0.5) to Apache Cassandra(3.11.3)

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

We are trying to migrate/replicate data from a DSE Cassandra node to apache Cassandra node.

Have done POC of that on the local machine and getting a schema version problem. 
Below are the details of the POC and the occurring problem.

**DSE Cassandra node Details:**

**dse_version:** 6.0.5
**release_version:** 4.0.0.605
**sstable format:**

```
aa-1-bti-CompressionInfo.db  
aa-1-bti-Digest.crc32  
aa-1-bti-Partitions.db  
aa-1-bti-Statistics.db  
aa-1-bti-Data.db  
aa-1-bti-Filter.db  
aa-1-bti-Rows.db  
aa-1-bti-TOC.txt
```

**Apache Cassandra node Details:**

**release_version:** 3.11.3
**sstable format:**

```
mc-1-big-CompressionInfo.db  
mc-1-big-Digest.crc32  
mc-1-big-Statistics.db  
mc-1-big-Data.db  
mc-1-big-Filter.db  
mc-1-big-TOC.txt  
mc-1-big-Summary.db
```

There is 1 cluster(My Cluster) in which I have a total of 4 nodes.

2 dse nodes(lets say DSE1 and DSE2) are in one Datacenter(i.e., dc1).
2 apache nodes(lets say APC1 and APC2) are in other Datacenter(i.e., dc2).

**Note:** I have used **NetworkTopologyStrategy** Topology Strategy for keyspace and **GossipingPropertyFileSnitch** as endpoint_snitch. Have added 
**$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.allow_unsafe_replace=true** in **cassandra-env.sh** file also.

When I am creating keyspace on **DSE1 node** with following CQL query:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE abc
    WITH REPLICATION = {
    'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
    'dc1' : 2,
    'dc2' : 2
}
AND DURABLE_WRITES = true;
```

The keyspace is getting created on **DSE2 node** but the following error is thrown by **cqlsh**:
**Warning: schema version mismatch detected; check the schema versions of your nodes in system.local and system.peers**

Also the following error is thrown from **one of the 2 Apache nodes(APC1/APC2)**:
**org.apache.cassandra.db.UnknownColumnFamilyException: Couldn't find table for cfId 02559ab1-91ee-11ea-8450-2df21166f6a4. If a table was just created, this is likely due to the schema not being fully propagated.  Please wait for schema agreement on table creation**

Have checked the schema version also **on all 4 nodes**, getting below result:

```
Cluster Information:
    Name: My Cluster
    Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
    DynamicEndPointSnitch: enabled
    Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
    Schema versions:
       84c22c85-8165-398f-ab9a-e25a6169b7d3: [127.0.0.4, 127.0.0.6]

       4c451173-5a05-3691-9a14-520419f849da: [127.0.0.5, 127.0.0.7]
```

Have tried to resolve the same using solution given in the following link:
https://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2019/04/03/cassandra-fix-schema-disagreement/

But the problem still persists.

Also, Can we migrate data from DSE Cassandra node to apache Cassandra node naturally as suggested in the following link:
[Migrate Datastax Enterprise Cassandra to Apache Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48968978/migrate-datastax-enterprise-cassandra-to-apache-cassandra)

Can anyone please suggest, how to overcome the problem. Is there any other upgradation or compatibility fix we need to implement to resolve this.